# Cannot find module '../xcode' Require stack - React Native - Expo cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I just want to create my first project using React Native in iOS with [expo.io](https://expo.io/learn). However, I got this error when I use this command "expo start" :

https://ibb.co/f2xsmpN

[image]

I already tried to reinstall and update Xcode, I tried to use sudo for permissions and I also tried this but it doesn't work:

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/react-native-community/cli/948/583759785

For more information, you can check this video and you can see in the min 11:20 he uses this command line.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sJQBjn_cRQ

I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: installing the XCode CLI tools is different than installing Xcode. `sudo xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem . I uninstalled expo-cli and nodejs and installed again. It works for me.

Comment: Can you replicate this? Or is this anecdotal?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I really don't know what's going behind but uninstalling expo-cli and nodejs was just instinct and it did work so !